# Powershell: Go through all files (PDF's) in a directory and move them based on what's written in the first 6 bytes

Tags: powershell, pdf

I am currently trying to write a powershell script that does the following:

- Go through all PDF-Files in the directory in which the script is in
- Check the first few bytes of those PDF-Files
- If those bytes say something along the lines of "PK", move them to a different location
- If the bytes say something else (ex: PDF1.4), dont move them at all and go to the next one.

Context: We have around 70k PDF-Files that cant be opened. After checking them with a certain tool, it looks like around 99% of those are damaged and the remaining 1% are zip files.
The first bytes of a zipped PDF file start with "PK", the first bytes of a broken PDF-File start with PDF1.4 for example.
I need to unzip all zip files and relocate them. Going through 70k PDF-Files by hand is kinda painful, so im looking for a way to automate it.

I know im supposed to provide a code sample, but the truth is that i am absolutely lost. I have written a few powershell scripts before, but i have no idea how to do something like this.

So, if anyone could kindly point me to the right direction or give me a useful function, i would really appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "first bytes" please. Do you mean the first characters of the contents, the first characters of the title, or do you literally mean the raw bytes of the document (if you mean this, can I also ask why? it seems a bit of a strange thing to be using to organise your PDF documents with)

Comment: I edited the question so that the context is more clear. By "first bytes" i mean the first characters you see when you open a PDF file in notepad++.

Comment: I don't know what the tool told you about the damage but that's a lot of files to potentially lose. My company offers a free tool that check PDF files called PDF Checker https://www.datalogics.com/products/pdftools/pdf-checker/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Get-Content` to get your first 6 bytes as you asked.
We can then tie that into a loop on all the documents and configure a simple if statement to decide what to do next, e.g. move the file to another dir

**EDITED BASED ON YOUR COMMENT:**

```
$pdfDirectory = 'C:\Temp\struktur_id_1225\ext_dok'
$newLocation = 'C:\Path\To\New\Folder'

Get-ChildItem "$pdfDirectory" -Filter "*.pdf" | foreach { 
    if((Get-Content $_.FullName | select -first 1 ) -like "%PDF-1.5*"){
        $HL7 = $_.FullName.replace("ext_dok","MDM")
        $HL7 = $HL7.replace(".pdf",".hl7")
        move $_.FullName $newLocation;
        move $HL7 $newLocation
    }
}
```

Try using the above, which is also a bit easier to edit.

`$pdfDirectory` will need to be set to the folder containing the PDF Files

`$newLocation` will obviously be the new directory!

And you will still need to change the `-like "%PDF-1.5*"` to suit your search!

It should do the rest for you, give it a shot

**Another Edit**

I have mimicked your folder structure on my computer, and placed a few PDF files and matching HL7 files and the script is working perfectly.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! This absolutely solves my problem.

Comment: Just comment on this answer if you have trouble using it buddy I'll help you format the command

Comment: Well, there would be one more thing... But i dont necessarily want to burden you with that, so i'll just say it and if you dont want to look into it that's totally understandable because i think it's quite a big thing...

For every PDF, theres one associated HL7 file in a different [folder](https://ibb.co/bRTnsB8).

Would it somehow be possible to move the HL7 files to the same location, if their associated PDF file gets moved? PDF's and HL7 files that belong together have the exact same name.

Comment: Yeah if they have the exact same name that would be fairly easy, do you know the full path of the relevant HL7 file? Do they follow a pattern? e.g. The pdf is in `C:\folder-a\name.pdf` and the HL7 is in `C:\folder-b\name.HL7`, or could it be anywhere? Either way it's doable but it will depend on how we code it

Comment: Oh you added a Picture!

Comment: OK lets make this script a bit easier for you to use, and get it to do that too. Give me a sec

Comment: please see Edited Answer

Comment: Panomosh, this is working perfectly. Honestly, thank you so much for taking the time to help me. It's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Content` is not suited for PDF's, you'd want to use [iTextSharp](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp) to read PDF's.

Download the iTextSharp(found in [releases](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/releases)) and put the `itextsharp.dll` somewhere easy to find (ie. the folder your script is located in).

You can install the `.nupkg` by using `Install-Package`, or simply using an archive tool to extract the contents of the `.nupkg` file (it's basically a `.zip` file)

The code below adds every word on page 1 for each PDF separated by whitespace to an array. You can then test if the array contains your keyword

```bsh
Add-Type -Path  "C:\path\to\itextsharp.dll"
$pdfs = Get-ChildItem "C:\path\to\pdfs"  *.pdf

foreach ($pdf in $pdfs) {
    $reader = New-Object itextsharp.text.pdf.pdfreader -ArgumentList $pdf.Fullname

        $text = [iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor]::GetTextFromPage($reader,1).Split("")
        foreach($line in $text) {
           # do your test here
        }
    }
```

Comment: He does not want the actual text content from the PDF, he wants the raw content, e.g. as if you opened the file in notepad, please read his question.