# How to unzip all files in folder? (Not .zip extension)

Tags: powershell, zip, unzip

Currently, I am writing a script that moves PDF files that are wrongfully zipped to a certain folder. I have achieved that. The next thing I need to get to work, is that the zipped .pdf files get unzipped into a different folder.

This is my whole script. Everything except for the last 2 lines is dedicated to finding the PDF files that are zipped and moving them.

In the first parts, the script checks the first few bytes of every pdf file in the folder. If they start with "PK*", they are zip files and get moved to the zipped folder.
For every PDF/zip file, there is one associated HL7 file in the [folder next to it.](https://ibb.co/bRTnsB8)

These also need to get moved to the same folder. From there the zip files need to be unzipped and relocated to "unzipped"

The last 2 lines are for unzipping.

```
$pdfDirectory = 'Z:\Documents\16_Med._App\Auftraege\PDFPrzemek\struktur_id_1225\ext_dok'
$newLocation = 'Z:\Documents\16_Med._App\Auftraege\PDFPrzemek\Zip'

Get-ChildItem "$pdfDirectory" -Filter "*.pdf" | foreach { 
    if ((Get-Content $_.FullName | select -First 1 ) -like "PK*") {
        $HL7 = $_.FullName.Replace("ext_dok","MDM")
        $HL7 = $HL7.Replace(".pdf",".hl7")
        move $_.FullName $newLocation;
        move $HL7 $newLocation
    }
}

Get-ChildItem 'Z:\Documents\16_Med._App\Auftraege\PDFPrzemek\Zip' |
Expand-Archive -DestinationPath 'Z:\Documents\16_Med._App\Auftraege\PDFPrzemek\Zip\unzipped' -Force
```

This, sadly, doesn't work. 
I suspect that it's because these files dont have the .zip extension. The only Filter that works for `Expand-Archive` is .zip.

So I need to find a way to get this function to unzip the files, even though they dont have the fitting extension...

Comment: Just append the extension `.zip` when moving the file? `move $_.FullName (Join-Path $newLocation ($_.Name + '.zip'))`

Comment: Sounds like it could work, how would i implement that?


`Get-ChildItem 'Z:\Documents\16_Med._App\Auftraege\PDFPrzemek\Zip' |
Expand-Archive -DestinationPath 'Z:\Documents\16_Med._App\Auftraege\PDFPrzemek\Zip\unzipped' -Force`

Answer (score 0):

Like @Ansgar said this would be the way to go:

```
Param (
    $SourcePath = 'C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\PDF',
    $ZipFilesPath = 'C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\ZIP',
    $UnzippedFilesPath = 'C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\Unzipped'
)

$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

#region Test folders
@($SourcePath, $ZipFilesPath, $UnzippedFilesPath) | Where-Object {
    -not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $_)
} | ForEach-Object {
    throw "Path '$_' not found. Make sure that the folders exist before running the script."
}
#endregion

#region Get all files with extension .pdf
$Params = @{
    Path   = Join-Path -Path $SourcePath -ChildPath 'ext_dok'
    Filter = '*.pdf'
}
$PDFfiles = Get-ChildItem @Params

Write-Verbose "Got $($PDFfiles.count) files with extension '.pdf' from '$($Params.Path)'"
#endregion

#region Move PDF and HL7 files
$MDMpath = Join-Path -Path $SourcePath -ChildPath 'MDM'

foreach ($PDFfile in ($PDFfiles | Where-Object {
    (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-Object -First 1) -like 'PK*'})
) {
    $MoveParams = @{
        Path        = $PDFfile.FullName
        Destination = Join-Path -Path $ZipFilesPath -ChildPath ($PDFfile.BaseName + '.zip')
    }
    Move-Item @MoveParams
    Write-Verbose "Moved file '$($MoveParams.Path)' to '$($MoveParams.Destination)'"

    $GetParams = @{
        Path        = Join-Path -Path $MDMpath -ChildPath ($PDFfile.BaseName + '.hl7')
        ErrorAction = 'Ignore'
    }
    if ($HL7file = Get-Item @GetParams) {
        $MoveParams = @{
            Path        = $HL7file
            Destination = $ZipFilesPath
        }
        Move-Item @MoveParams
        Write-Verbose "Moved file '$($MoveParams.Path)' to '$($MoveParams.Destination)$($HL7file.Name)'"
    }
}
#endregion

#region Unzip files
$ZipFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $ZipFilesPath -Filter '*.zip' -File

foreach ($ZipFile in $ZipFiles) {
    $ZipFile | Expand-Archive -DestinationPath $UnzippedFilesPath -Force

    Write-Verbose "Unzipped file '$($ZipFile.Name)' in folder '$UnzippedFilesPath'"
}
#endregion
```

Some tips:

- Add a `Param ()` clause at the beginning of the script to contain all your variables that can change.
- Try to use the full parameter name to clearly indicate what is what. Use `Get-ChildItem -Path xxx` instead of `Get-ChildItem xxx`.
- Use `hash tables` for long parameters. This makes the code more compact in width and more easily to read.
- Use `#region` and `#endregion` to group your code.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but i dont really understand your answer... Did you rewrite my whole script? If so, the If statement checking if the PDF is actually a zip fell away now, and im not sure how to implement it again.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not explaining everything more properly.
I'll edit my answer so it includes more context. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57723615/powershell-go-through-all-files-pdfs-in-a-directory-and-move-them-based-on-w) is my first question on this topic, which also explains everything.

Comment: No, the HL7 file is not a ZIP file. It doesnt need to be modified in any way.

Comment: Great! This works almost perfectly! 
I just tested it, and there were 3 files contained in the ZIP files that were all called "scan.pdf".
Only one of those 3 with the same name got unzipped and moved to unzipped.

Do you have an idea what might be causing this?

Thank you very much for your very useful help!

Comment: They all got unzipped but the last one always overwrites the previous one with the same name. If you don't want that you should check the names of the unzipped files first and append a number to them

Comment: Taht does not seem to be possible, unless you extract each zip file to its own folder.

Comment: I think i have an idea... Would it be possible to rename the contents of the ZIP file to the original name of the ZIP file itself?

So, while unzipping and moving the contained file, rename the contained file to the original ZIP file name

That would help me see which files belong to which ZIP and it would give them all unique names.